# Python dynamically add decorator to class' methods by decorating class

Tags: python, aop, decorator

say I have a class:

```
class x:

    def first_x_method(self):
        print 'doing first_x_method stuff...'

    def second_x_method(self):
        print 'doing second_x_method stuff...'
```

and this decorator

```
class logger:
    @staticmethod
    def log(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                print "Entering: [%s] with parameters %s" % (func.__name__, args)
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception, e:
                    print 'Exception in %s : %s' % (func.__name__, e)
            finally:
                print "Exiting: [%s]" % func.__name__
        return wrapped
```

how would I write another decorator `otherdecorator` so that:

```
@otherdecorator(logger.log)
class x:

    def first_x_method(self):
        print 'doing x_method stuff...'

    def first_x_method(self):
        print 'doing x_method stuff...'
```

the same as

```
class x:
      @logger.log
      def first_x_method(self):
          print 'doing first_x_method stuff...'

      @logger.log
      def second_x_method(self):
        print 'doing second_x_method stuff...'
```

or in fact replace

```
@otherdecorator(logger.log)
class x:
```

with

```
@otherdecorator 
class x:
```

where otherdecorator  contains all the functionality
(I'm not a python person so be gentle)

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: 2.6 and Iron Python (clr 4.0/dlr)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unless there is a definite reason to use a class as a decorator, I think it is usually easier to use functions to define decorators.

Here is one way to create a class decorator `trace`, which decorates all methods of a class with the `log` decorator:

```
import inspect


def log(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print("Entering: [%s] with parameters %s" % (func.__name__, args))
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Exception in %s : %s' % (func.__name__, e))
        finally:
            print("Exiting: [%s]" % func.__name__)
    return wrapped


def trace(cls):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/17019983/190597 (jamylak)
    for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, lambda x: inspect.isfunction(x) or inspect.ismethod(x)):
        setattr(cls, name, log(m))

    return cls


@trace
class X(object):
    def first_x_method(self):
        print('doing first_x_method stuff...')

    def second_x_method(self):
        print('doing second_x_method stuff...')


x = X()
x.first_x_method()
x.second_x_method()
```

yields:

```
Entering: [first_x_method] with parameters (<__main__.X object at 0x7f19e6ae2e80>,)
doing first_x_method stuff...
Exiting: [first_x_method]
Entering: [second_x_method] with parameters (<__main__.X object at 0x7f19e6ae2e80>,)
doing second_x_method stuff...
Exiting: [second_x_method]
```

Comment: So presumably I could add the decorator at run time with a settattr on the type to secorate?

Comment: @Preet Sangha: Yes, I don't think there would be any problem -- except that instances of the class made before the decorator is applied will not be modified.

Comment: @unutbu, my Python version is 3.6.8 and the running result is:```doing first_x_method stuff...
doing second_x_method stuff...```

Comment: @Tengerye: The code above has now been updated for Python3. The main difference is that in Python3 the [method is just a plain function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17019983/190597) so the predicate needs to be changed to `inspect.isfunction` instead of `inspect.ismethod`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of the `trace` decorator implemented as a class which allows for the other use case asked for: passing in the function to decorate all member functions of the decorated class with.

```
import inspect


def log(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print "Entering: [%s] with parameters %s" % (func.__name__, args)
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception, e:
                print 'Exception in %s : %s' % (func.__name__, e)
        finally:
            print "Exiting: [%s]" % func.__name__
    return wrapped


class trace(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, cls):
        for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
            setattr(cls, name, self.f(m))
        return cls


@trace(log)
class X(object):

    def first_x_method(self):
        print 'doing first_x_method stuff...'

    def second_x_method(self):
        print 'doing second_x_method stuff...'

x = X()
x.first_x_method()
x.second_x_method()
```