# Rewrite python function without inspect module

Tags: python, reflection, introspection

How would I write this introspective function without using the inspect module.

```
import inspect

def trace(cls):
    for name, m in inspect.getmembers(cls, inspect.ismethod):
        setattr(cls,name,log(m))
    return cls
```

The above is from [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481623/python-dynamically-add-decorator-to-class-methods-by-decorating-class/5481729#5481729)

**Edit/Clarification:
Is it possible to do this without any imports also?**

Note this is not a real use case rather a pure and simple case of curiosity on my part.

Comment: What is meant by "didn't have access to the import module"? You can `import` inside the function `trace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
>>> class Tester(object):
...   def mymethod(self):
...     return True
... 
>>> hasattr(Tester, 'mymethod')
True
>>> hasattr(Tester.mymethod, 'im_func')
True
```

from the python docs on the [data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)  scroll down a bit to get to "user defined methods".

> `Special read-only attributes: im_self is the class instance object, im_func is the function object; im_class is the class of im_self for bound methods or the class that asked for the method for unbound methods; __doc__ is the method’s documentation (same as im_func.__doc__); __name__ is the method name (same as im_func.__name__); __module__ is the name of the module the method was defined in, or None if unavailable.`

im_func and im_self as of 2.6 are also availabale as `__func__` and `__self__` respectively.
I sort of tend to gravitate here than use the inspect module myself.

Comment: `class NotAMethod(object): im_func = not True`

Answer (score 2):

What `inspect.ismethod` does is [simply](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/inspect.py#l79):

```
import types
def ismethod(obj):
   return isinstance(obj, types.MethodType)
```

and `types.MethodType` is [defined as](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/types.py#l20):

```
class _C:
   def _m(self): pass
MethodType = type(_C()._m)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using inspect i will do it like this:

```
import types

def trace(cls):
    for attr_name in cls.__dict__:
        attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
        if isinstance(attr, types.MethodType):
            setattr(cls, attr_name, log(attr))
    return cls
```

**EDIT:**

Your constrain are a bit weird but let see :

We can replace `if isinstance(attr, types.MethodType)` by `if callable(attr)` this will give us only callable attribute of the class which include also static methods and class methods ...

We can also do as the other answer suggest use `if hasattr(attr, 'im_func')` this will exclude the static methods.

If we want to exclude class method too (only get instance method), i think the only solution i'm aware off now (without importing an other module) is by changing the decorator to check if the first argument is a class or an instance, this can give you a hint if the method that will be decorated is a class or a instance method.

Hope it help :)

Comment: @Preet Sangha: i just edited my answer given your new edit :)