# Can a python unittest class add an assert statement for each test method in a parent class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop

I have a unit test class that is a sub-class of python's `unittest`:

```
import unittest

class MyTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    run_parameters = {param1: 'on'}
    def someTest(self):
        self.assertEquals(something, something_else)
```

Now I want to create a child class that modifies, say `run_parameters`, and adds an additional assert statement on top of what was already written:

```
class NewWayToRunThings_TestClass(MyTestClass):
        run_parameters = {param1: 'blue'}
        # Want someTest, and all other tests in MyTestClass to now run 
        # with an additional assert statement
```

Is there someway to accomplish this so that each test runs with an additional assert statement to check that my parameter change worked properly across all my tests?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481623/python-dynamically-add-decorator-to-class-methods-by-decorating-class

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is but it may not be a good idea because:

- assertions are hidden behind difficult to understand python magic
- assertions aren't explicit

Could you update your methods to reflect the new contract, and expected param?

Also if a single parameter change breaks a huge amount of tests, where it is easier to dynamically patch the test class then it is to update the tests, the test suite may not be focused enough.