# Pre process arguments passed to all instance methods in Python

Tags: python, class, methods, arguments, preprocessor

```
class SimpleClass(object):
     def A(self, *args):
          ...
     def B(self, *args):
          ...
     def C(self, *args):
          ...
```

Is there anyway to catch the arguments passed to A, B, C, modify those arguments and pass the modified arguments onto A, B, C without having to modify the existing code ?

Edit:

Answer: use a class decorator, that decorates all methods of the class with another decorator.

The method decorator performs the pre-processing.

Comment: You can do with with [decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python).

Comment: but would that require adding decorators to each class method ?

Comment: oh you can create a decorator for that class that decorate each class method with another decorator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481623/python-dynamically-add-decorator-to-class-methods-by-decorating-class

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from types import FunctionType

class SimpleClass(object):
    def A(self, *args):
        pass
    def B(self, *args):
        pass
    def C(self, *args):
        pass


def methods(cls):
    """List of all method in class."""
    return [x for x, y in cls.__dict__.items() if type(y) == FunctionType]

def args_decorator(method):
    """Decorator for SimpleClass methods"""
    def wrapper(self, *args):
        new_args = list(args)
        # change new_args here
        return method(self, *new_args)
    return wrapper


for method in methods(SimpleClass):
    setattr(SimpleClass, method, args_decorator(SimpleClass.__dict__[method]))
```

Though if you can change your `SimpleClass` I'd suggest using decorator like so:

```
def args_decorator(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args):
        new_args = list(args)
        # change new_args here
        return method(self, *new_args)
    return wrapper

class SimpleClass(object):
    @args_decorator
    def A(self, *args):
        pass
    @args_decorator
    def B(self, *args):
        pass
    @args_decorator
    def C(self, *args):
        pass
```